# Python library for taking camera images

Tags: library, python, images, webcam

I want to get a single image from a camera (e.g. a built-in webcam in a notebook) with Python.

I'm looking for a library that makes this possible in a few lines of code (I'm not looking to write a camera driver or anything like that). The image should be in some standard bitmap format.

Please also

- list requirements (e.g. installed packages, operating system),
- add a link to the documentation

Comment: This question has been migrated to [softwarerecs.se]. I have edited your title to be more on-topic here, and removed two requirements that you cannot reasonably expect to be fulfilled here. You can revert the edit if you disagree.

Comment: For all answers, please note http://stackoverflow.com/a/34687991/562769

Comment: Please tell us your operating system: linux, mac, windows ...

Answer (score 6):

## [SimpleCV](http://simplecv.org/)

- Requirements:

  - Packages: `simplecv` (and `Pygame`?)
  - Python 2.X only
  - OS: works on Linux (tested with Ubuntu)
- Documenttion: [simplecv.org/docs/](http://simplecv.org/docs/)
- Code: [github.com/sightmachine/simplecv](https://github.com/sightmachine/simplecv)

### Installation

On Debian-based systems:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

### Code

```
import time
from SimpleCV import Camera

cam = Camera()
time.sleep(0.1)  # If you don't wait, the image will be dark
img = cam.getImage()
img.save("simplecv.png")
```

### SimpleCV image

[image]

Although the lighting situation did not change, the Python image is much darker. I'm not sure why that is the case.

Comment: My first guess is that the python image is scaled from 0-1 whereas it should be 0-255.

Comment: @Dirk: Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Multiply by 255, then save it as png :)

Comment: @Dirk: This seems not to be the problem. I printed a single pixel and it showed the RGBA value  with integers. So I guess a 0..255 range is used. However, I am not sure why it was RGBA and not RGB.

Comment: I've just filed an issue [Camera image is very dark](https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/issues/665) for SimpleCV. Lets see if they know how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

## [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)

- Requirements:

  - Packages: `cv2` (not in PyPI)
  - Python 2.X (not tested with 3 though)
- OS: Works on Ubuntu
- Documentation: http://opencv.org/documentation.html

### Installation

On Debian-based systems:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

### Code

```
import time
import cv2
camera_port = 0
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
time.sleep(0.1)  # If you don't wait, the image will be dark
return_value, image = camera.read()
cv2.imwrite("opencv.png", image)
del(camera)  # so that others can use the camera as soon as possible
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks, I've added it. Do you know if the other have / need something similar?

Comment: `cam.stop()` in pygame

Answer (score 3):

## PyGame

This answer is partially taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11094891/562769 - thanks [Froyo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11094891/562769)!

Thanks to [Phani](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/26598/phani) for helping me to improve it.

- Requirements:

  - Packages: pygame (not in PyPI)
  - Python 2.X (not tested with 3 though)
  - OS: Works on Ubuntu
- Documentation: http://www.pygame.org/docs/

### Installation

On Debian-based systems:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

### Code

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
import time

pygame.camera.init()
pygame.camera.list_cameras()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0", (640, 480))
cam.start()
time.sleep(0.1)  # You might need something higher in the beginning
img = cam.get_image()
pygame.image.save(img, "pygame.jpg")
cam.stop()
```

Comment: It will be useful to add a `time.sleep(0.1)` here as well. Otherwise, the images are dark

Comment: The sleep has to be after `cam.start()`. Also, for me `0.1` is not enough on my Dell laptop. `0.5` worked for me.

Comment: @Phani Very interesting. I tested it a couple of times and I guess 0.1 was to low for my computer, too. However, after running my script a couple of times I don't need the "sleep" line of code. The last thing I tried was putting the sleep between `cam = ...` and `cam.start()`. I (wrongly) assumed that it has to be there, because it worked after changing that.

Comment: On windows 7, py36, I get `ImportError: cannot import name '_camera'`.

Answer (score 3):

i just modified the @Martin Thoma Code.

```
import cv2
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    return_value,image = camera.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('image',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF == ord('s'):
        cv2.imwrite('test.jpg',image)
        break
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

to resolve the black screen problem. i hope it'll be help. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## [ecapture](https://pypi.org/project/ecapture/)

Installation

```
pip install ecapture
```

Code

```
from ecapture import ecapture as ec

ec.capture(0,"test","img.jpg")
```

Answer (score -1):

I would cut this problem into two pieces.

1. Take a picture from the command line

I hope you use an operating system like linux which has a command line.
AFAIK gphoto2 can do something like this

2. Use the Python subprocess module

   subprocess.call(['yourtoo', 'arg1, ...])

Answer (score -3):

To solve the black screen problem, let the cam warms up.

```
import time 
import cv2
camera_port = 0
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
time.sleep(0.1)
return_value, image = camera.read()
cv2.imwrite("opencv.jpg", image)
del(camera)  # so that others can use the camera as soon as possible
```

Comment: Which is exactly what I wrote in the comment above 2 months ago. If you think it should be an answer, you should at least make it a community wiki answer.